# Find the subgroup $H$ of $A_4$ generated by $(123)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need to find the subgroup $H \leq A_4$ generated by $(123).$ I know that this subgroup will have order 1,2,3,4,6, or 12.

Comment: What have you tried? This exercise just involved multiplying a few permutations.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The order of a cycle is equal to its length. If the length of a cycle $\sigma$ is $k$, then the group it generates is given by $\{\sigma, \sigma^2, \ldots, \sigma^k\}$.

Comment: how do we know that our new subgroup H is cyclic?

Comment: We know it is cyclic because *every* group that is generated by *one* element is cyclic. That is, for any group $G$, if $\alpha \in G$, then $H = \langle \alpha \rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$, and recall that $\langle \alpha \rangle = \{\alpha^k\mid 0 \leq k \leq k-1\}$ where $k$ represents the order of the $\langle \alpha\rangle$. Note also that the identity is given by $\alpha^0 = \alpha^k$.

Comment: Levi, if you've found an answer to be helpful, we encourage you to accept it. You can accept only one answer per question you ask, and to accept an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it, and you receive 2 reputation points when you accept an answer.

Comment: @amWhy: Another TU -->> +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $(123)^2 = (132)$, and since it's a $3$-cycle, $(123)^3$ is the identity permutation.